# List initialization of classes with private members

Tags: c++, c++11

The `std::vector` allows list initialization like the following:

```
std::vector a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

As far as I can tell, the underlying members of `std::vector` are private, you can access the data array like `a.data()` but the actual members are `private`. Correct, me if I am wrong.

So how can I mimic this with my own class? I know that if your members are public you can do it:

```
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<int> a;
    std::map<int, int> b;
};

A a = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};
```

But say I have the following a simple class which has a private member, just like a vector say for example: **The limited length list**

```
class LimitedLengthList
{

    LimitedLengthList(int length) : maxLength(length){};
    int operator[]
    etc etc

private:
    int maxLength;
    std::vector<int> list;  
};
```

How can I expose this to aggregate initialization and impose sanctions such as max length on it? Is it possible to do something like this:

```
LimitedLengthList a(5) = {1, 2, 3};
```

or this:

```
LimitedLengthList a = {1, {1, 2, 3}};
```

Comment: `vector`'s initialization is not aggregate initialization. It's list initialization, using a constructor taking a `std::initializer_list`.

Comment: @T.C. So it is, knowing that would have made my research easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) (see ctor 7) , you need to provide a constructor that takes a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Something like

```
class LimitedLengthList
{
public:
  LimitedLengthList(std::initializer_list<T> init, int length = somedefaultval)
    : maxLength(length), list(std::move(init)) {}
  LimitedLengthList(int length) : maxLength(length){};
  int operator[]
  etc etc

private:
  int maxLength;
  std::vector<int> list;  
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You may do:

```
LimitedLengthList(int length, std::vector<int> v) :
        maxLength(length),
        list(std::move(v))
    {
        if (list.size() >= maxLength) {
            throw runtime_error("Bad size");
        }
    }
```

So `LimitedLengthList a = {1, {0, 1, 2}};` will take this constructor
and use initializer-list constructor of vector for the `{0, 1, 2}` part.

Comment: I'd take `v` by value rather than by const ref and do `list(std::move(v))`.